# How can I place a colored box behind the slideshow?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

I tried to do it with the .myslides-colorbox on the html/css. The background always seems to cut of at the edge of the top of the slideshow. I want the slide-show to be over a big box [image] something like this is what I want to do with the slideshow. What do I have to add or place differently to make this happen? *The controller represent my slideshow*

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n >= x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    /* background-color: red; */
    padding-left: 8%;
    /* padding-right: 8%; */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Navigation bar section*/

.navbar {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.logo {
    width: 150px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 30px;
}

#menu-icon {
    width: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

nav {
    flex: 1;
    text-align: right;
}

nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 20px;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    color:blue
}


.row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 100px 0;
}

.col-1 {
    flex-basis: 40%;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.col-1 h2{
    font-size: 54px;
}

.col-1 h3{
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #707070;
    font-weight: 100;
    margin: 20px 0 10px;
}

.col-1 p {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #b7b7b7;
    font-weight: 100;
}

.col-1 h4{
    margin: 30px 0;
    font-size: 20px;
}

button {
    width: 140px;
    border: 0;
    padding: 12px 10px;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #fb5283, #ff3527);
    border-radius: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
    /* transition: width 0.5s; */
}

/* button i {
    width: 30px;
    display: none;
} */

button:hover {
    width: 160px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff3527, #fb5283);
}

.col-1::after {
    content: '';
    width: 10px;
    height: 57%;
    background: linear-gradient(#fb5283, #ff3527);
    position: absolute;
    left: -40px;
    top: 8px;
}

.col-2 {
    position: relative;
    flex-basis: 60%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: 200px;
}

.mySlides-colorBox {
    position:sticky;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(#fb5283, #ff3527);
    /* border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px; */
    height: 100%;
    width: 80%;
    z-index: -1;
    transform: translate(15);
}

.mySlides {display:none;}


.box{
    width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 5px solid blue;
    margin: 20px auto;
    position: relative;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/15456887b7.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar">
            <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTU3DPk4gCVZ0g40k0xiOjiwcqGY9MJkY4quA&usqp=CAU" class="logo">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="auction.html">Auction</a></li>
                    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="proceedings.html">Proceedings</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <i class="fa-solid fa-bars" id="menu-icon"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-1">
                <h2>Come see our wonderful things!</h2>
                <h3>Finnspeed Oy on perustettu vuonna 1995. Se on osakeyhtiö, jonka kotipaikka on Järvenpää, ja pääasiallinen toimiala Autoliike. Yhtiön toimitusjohtaja on Keijo Tapani Lehtonen.
                    Yhtiön Finnspeed Oy liikevaihto oli 46 tuhatta ja tilikauden tulos 13 tuhatta. Liikevaihto nousi 58,6%. Liikevoittoprosentti oli 37%. Tiedot perustuvat yhtiön viimeisimpään tilinpäätökseen vuodelta 2021.</h3>
                <p>more info....</p>
                <h4>Free entry</h4>
                <button type="button">Button <i class="fa-solid fa-gavel"></i></button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <div class="image-container">
                    <img class="mySlides active" src="https://d1yb6h7rvkcay2.cloudfront.net/f6/d7/91/b0/c4/a8/41/a1/a4/da/02/38/c8/de/dd/6c/f6d791b0-c4a8-41a1-a4da-0238c8dedd6c-large::r:0.jpg" style="width:50%">
                    <img class="mySlides" src="https://d1yb6h7rvkcay2.cloudfront.net/aa/8e/9c/02/aa/1d/48/f4/82/a1/63/f1/fa/c8/bb/52/aa8e9c02-aa1d-48f4-82a1-63f1fac8bb52-large::r:0.jpg" style="width:50%">
                    <img class="mySlides" src="https://d1yb6h7rvkcay2.cloudfront.net/98/5f/b3/11/a1/b5/49/0e/b4/71/82/1e/a4/c7/18/60/985fb311-a1b5-490e-b471-821ea4c71860-large::r:0.jpg" style="width:50%">
                    <img class="mySlides" src="https://d1yb6h7rvkcay2.cloudfront.net/1d/03/8b/7c/66/36/45/19/98/b2/17/1a/fc/be/b9/e5/1d038b7c-6636-4519-98b2-171afcbeb9e5-large::r:0.jpg" style="width:50%">
                  
                    <button class="mySlides-leftButton" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
                    <button class="mySlides-rightButton" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>

                    <div class="mySlides-colorBox"></div>
                  </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
        <div class="item1"></div>
        <div class="item2"></div>
        <div class="item3"></div>
        <div class="item4"></div>
    </div>      
    


    <script src="index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might wanna set that background on `.container`

Comment: but I only need a background on the slide show. I added the rest of the code